# How to remove the toolbar from Android app codenameone (make it fullscreen)

Tags: java, codenameone

I have tried everything but this toolbar does not want to leave I have even tried setting the color to black so it just rhymes with the background of the app with no avail.

I have tried hiding the toolbar globally that didn't work then I tried hiding the toolbar for just the form that still didn't work.

How do I resolve this? screenshot of app:
[image: screenshot of app]

Comment: off topic question

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: this is a programming question using codenameone to develop an android application

Comment: When tagging with Java make sure to include actual Java code so readers who aren't familiar with Codename One won't be confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
getToolbar().setUIID("Container");
```

If this doesn't work open the `Component Inspector` tool from the simulator and inspect the elements within. Look at the top area of the screen and see which UIID/Component is taking up that space.